# Speeding up API Response Time

Tags: python, performance, api, cassandra

I wish reduce the complete time a web server to REQUEST/RECEIVE data from an API server for a given query.

Assuming MySQL as bottleneck, I updated the API server db to Cassandra, but still complete time remains the same. May be something else is a bottleneck which I could not figure out.

**Environment:**

```
Number of Request Estimated per minute: 100
Database: MySQl / Cassandra
Hardware: EC2 Small
Server Used: Apache HTTP
```

**Current Observations:**

```
Cassandra Query Response Time: .03 Secs 
Time between request made and response received: 4 Secs
```

**Required:**

```
Time between request made and response received: 1 Secs
```

**BOTTOM LINE: How can we reduce the complete time taken in this given case?**

*Feel free to ask for more details if required. Thanks*

Comment: Where are you measuring the time between request and response from? In the web server logs? Monitoring software on the server? Client on the same machine? Client on the same network? Or a client on the other side of the world?

Comment: How do you interface your back end into Apache?

Comment: Are you measuring the web performance using a single request or by applying a load to it? If you are applying a load, what is the rate of requests, and how do you generate the load?

Comment: @AndrewAlcock: The request and response machine are under same network (We are using EC2 US machines for each of them)

Comment: We are measuring the web performance using a web crawler (curl multithreaded) making 100 request in parallel. In other test we used single threaded crawler.

Comment: We interface our back end into Apache using a python code. (Please correct me if I dint get the question) And we tested python code - Cassandra query time it was around .03 secs

Comment: Can you run a tool like 'top' during your load test? This can tell you, for example, if your machine is loaded (CPU maxed out) or memory under stress (paging and IOWait) or idle. Knowing this helps the diagnosis path

Comment: 'top' sounds good. Lemme run it and share results here in a while. Thanks

Comment: When you ran the 100 HTTP requests, you are reporting an average of 4s? What was the *distribution* of values: the minimum time, the max time and the standard deviation?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14317/discussion-between-andrew-alcock-and-dragosrsupercool)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing from the chat:

- Environment:

  - Running on a small Amazon EC2 instance (1 virtual CPU, 1.7GB RAM)
  - Web server is Apache
  - 100 worker threads
  - Python is using Pylons (which implies WSGI)
  - Test client in the EC2
- Tests:

  - 1.8k requests, single thread

    - Unknown CPU cost
    - Cassandra request time: 0.079s (spread 0.048->0.759)
    - MySQL request time: 0.169s (spread 0.047->1.52)
  - 10k requests, multiple threads

    - CPU runs at 90%
    - Cassandra request time: 2.285s (spread 0.102->6.321)
    - MySQL request time: 7.879s (spread 0.831->14.065)

**Observation**: 100 threads is probably a **lot** too many on your small EC2 instance. Bear in mind that each thread spawns a Python process which occupies memory and resources - even when not doing anything. Reducing the threads reduces:

- Memory contention (and memory paging *kills* performance)
- CPU buffer misses
- CPU contention
- DB contention

**Recommendation**: You should aim to run only as many threads as are needed to max out your CPU (but fewer if they max out on memory or other resources). Running more threads increases overheads and decreases throughput.

**Observation**: Your best performance time in single-threaded mode gives a probable best-case cost of 0.05 CPU-seconds per request. Assuming some latency (waits for IO), your CPU cost may be quite a lot lower). Assuming CPU is the bottleneck in your architecture, you probably are capable of 20-40 transactions a second on your EC2 server with just thread tuning.

**Recommendation**: Use a standard Python profiler to profile the system (when running with an optimum number of threads). The profiler will indicate where the CPU spends the most time. Distinguish between waits (i.e. for the DB to return, for disk to read or write data) vs. the inherent CPU cost of the code.

- Where you have a high inherent CPU cost: can you decrease the cost? If this is not in your code, can you avoid that code path by doing something different? Caching? Using another library?
- Where there is latency: Given your single-threaded results, latency is not necessarily bad **assuming** that the CPU can service another request. In fact you can get a rough idea on the number of threads you need by calculating: (total time / (total time - wait time))
   However, check to see that, while Python is waiting, the DB (for instance) isn't working hard to return a result.

**Other thoughts**: Consider how the test harness delivers HTTP requests - does it do so as fast as it can (eg tries to open 10k TCP sockets simultaneously?) If so, this may be skewing your results. It may be better to use a different loading pattern and tool.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra works faster on high load and average time of 3 - 4 secs on a two system on different sides of the world is ok.